# How to Store a multiple values( during run time) in a map and getting a single value again

Tags: java, list, dictionary, automation, runtime

```java
Iterator searchGetResponseIterator = searchGetResponse.entrySet().iterator();
Object obj = null;
Object dataPicker = null;
while(searchGetResponseIterator.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry searchGetResponseElement = (Map.Entry)searchGetResponseIterator.next();
    if(searchGetResponseElement.getKey().equals("seSearch")) {
        obj = searchGetResponseElement.getValue();
    }
}
```

want to store the `"obj"` in map. In obj i have this >>

```
{"columns":[{"exp":{"$ali":"t2acName"},"ali":"sourceacName"},"**id**":"4c99eedc836adbeefd0e10db76a","**table**":"public.4c99eedc836adbeefd0e10db76a","fieldIds":["0336e7c7-b236-41b7-8ae8-194dcfc49693","369bc4de-b220-41a2-a7be-090c6386aa2e","37926ca2-044f-44f2-a349-0f2e1b61f120","2310dcca-010f-4830-b300-01fb00d2d15e","306554be-92b3-41a3-bb24-b59f4adc8b79","21cdee98-e3b4-4da9-a502-587c0a221413","1f26c177-944f-4378-9e26-8ee0882221cc","13532fa7-8320-4cc1-90fb-aa8fcc3f5f6f","16d3a857-e8d5-4172-87f5-a149187ec409",],"executionQueue":[{"flow":0,"start":1574674632999,"count":0,"rEnd":1574676432999,"status":"done"},{"flow":0,"start":1574620200000,"count":0,"rEnd":1574674632999,"status":"done"}]}
```

and i want to get **id** and **table** from table again.

Comment: what is stored in Map? string or custom class instance?

Comment: In map we are storing a Response Body in key and value formate. In one of the key we are getting value as in this obj So now I want to fetch id and table values .

Comment: You need to use `ObjectMapper` and convert this response string to a map and get your values.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way is to convert the Object string to a map and get your fields.

```
if(searchGetResponseElement.getKey().equals("seSearch")) {
   obj = searchGetResponseElement.getValue();
   ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
   HashMap responseMap = objectMapper.readValue(obj.toString(), HashMap.class);
}
```

Once you have the `responseMap`, you can inspect that object and get the required hierarchy from it.

For example: `((Map) ((List) responseMap.get("columns")).get(0)).get("id")`

`Note:` The above example may not accurately represent your response model.

Comment: The method readValue(JsonParser, Class<T>) in the type ObjectMapper is not applicable for the arguments (Object, Class<HashMap>)

Comment: Can you try with `objectMapper.readValue(obj.toString(), HashMap.class)` ?

Comment: Please note that OP's example is not really a valid JSON

Answer (score 0):

You know the format of obj

```
{"**id**":"4c99eedc836adbeefd0e10db76a","**table**":"public.
```

Looks like there is consistent pattern where **id** appears, and where **table** appears in that blob of string / json.

Look at RegEx java tutorial and create one to extract id and table

https://www.baeldung.com/regular-expressions-java